# PHP Code formatting got messy when uploaded to server

Tags: php

PHP scripts on ide looks reular before uplode to server.But When Its uploaded to server its structure Corrupts.Im using FileZilla for Uploading.

***Example :***

**Before Upload**

```
<?php 
 echo 'This is';
 echo 'Regular';
 echo 'Code';
?>
```

---

**After Upload**

```
<?php 
 echo 'This is';
 echo 'Corrupted';
 echo 'Code';
?>
```

---

Comment: use binary mode to upload file. also remove closing php tag from your file

Comment: How do you say it's "corrupting"?

Comment: [Wat](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CFReYwSwFbc)?

Comment: Funny how those edits got approved...

Answer (score 2):

Your files are not "**`corrupted`**". The **FTP** Transfer setting is the cause for this..

Cause.. [Read the bold text]

> FileZilla does not analyse files uploaded as ASCII in any way. So if
>   you have mixed line endings, somewhat "unexpected" things can happen.
>   The native line ending for Windows is CR+LF. As this is what the FTP
>   server expects when transferring files in ASCII, FileZilla on Windows
>   does not apply any line ending translation at all. Now, imagine there
>   is a text file with mixed Windows (CR+LF) and Unix (LF) line endings.
>   **Uploading that file from a Windows-based system to a Unix-based system
>   will result in all CR+LF translated to LF only**.

Follow..

- Choose Transfer -> Transfer type
- Set the upload action transfer to Auto detect, ASCII or binary.

[`Source`](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Data_Type)

Comment: The problem may also be `\r\n` vs. `\n` line terminators. But without clarifications from OP we can't know for sure.